# Body is not set 100% height on android devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have View where body must be 100% height.

Here is code of page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Евгений Соя</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="mini.png"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
   <div class="logo">
       <img  class="graficlogo" src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
   </div> 
   <nav>
       <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
           <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
           <a href="tour.html">Тур</a>
           <a href="books.html">Книги</a>
           <a  id="menu" href="#" class="icon">&#9776;</a>
       </div>
   </nav> 
     
</header>
   
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div class="main">
      <h1> "Времени пленница "-

новая песня Марии Чайковской по мотивам стихов Евгения Сои доступна <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/ru/album/%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-single/1386924933"> iTunes.</a></h1>
      <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/yessoya/"> <img  class="embl1" src="INSTAGRAM_icon.png"></a>
      <a href="https://www.stihi.ru/avtor/sunfish"><img  class="embl2"
      src="111.png"></a>
  </div>
</body>
    
</html>
```

Full code is here

> https://codepen.io/suhomlineugene/pen/MXPGPN

When I open it on ios device all ok and I see this

[ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXypC.jpg)

On android it is like this

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOqVl.jpg)

I don't understand why, if I had body 100% width and height.

How I can solve it?

Comment: try using `height:100vh` instead of `100%` on `body`

Comment: already tried, not helping @MihaiT

Comment: i can't find any problem in my android mobile on visiting your website.  what model you had checked and had you checked on different browsers??

Comment: just tried on my android... background is full... no issue

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself

Comment: height of your body is correct but your inner container have to set as `height:100%`...!